# Identify jenkins error messages for failed tests and debugging

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins

Is it possible to find out why the tests on the jenkins server failed? Meaning like an error message? I am new to testing and although I did some front end testing with Chutzpah, this is a totally new concept. Could someone please throw a light on this?Also, is there anyway to debug my tests in jenkins?
I am running my tests on visual studio and all the tests are passing but when I run them on jenkins, I see that some of them are failing and some of them are passing

Answer (score 0):

There should be a "Console log" link on each test; click on that.

Answer (score 0):

As Oli Charlesworth sad use the "console log" (+1) there you get (nearly) same errors like in VS. Mostly I scroll down to the end of the log and search for the error bottom up, because the error is usually one of the last actions.

I do not know anyway how you can debug tests in Jenkins.